# Определить, является ли текст правильной записью римскими цифрами целого числа

Tags: pascal

Помогите решить, не могу понять задачу. Или объясните как ее решать:

> Дан текст из заглавных латинских букв, за которым следует пробел. Определить, является ли этот текст правильной записью римскими цифрами целого числа от 1 до 999, и если является, то напечатать это число арабскими цифрами.

Comment: что конкретно не понятно? тебе дается строка, надо определить, является ли она записью римского числа. если да, вывести это арабское число.

Comment: @Yasha попробуйте решить задачу на бумаге руками, потом запишите алгоритм на Pascal

Comment: интересно, за что этому вопросу можно было поставить плюс?

Comment: Черт, не посмотрел на дату вопроса перед правкой =(